# Closed-form solution for the integral of the ratio of two sums?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Is there a closed-form solution for this integral?

$$\int_0^t\frac{\sum_{k=1}^Nr_{1k}\exp(ixr_{2k})}{\sum_{k=1}^N\exp(ixr_{2k})}dx$$

for given $r_{11},...,r_{1N},r_{21},...,r_{2N} \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Are we assuming that $r_{ij}\in\Bbb R$?

Comment: @abiessu: Yes, we are. Thanks.